# How to access custom ds fields in page manager?

Tags: 7, display-suite, chaos-tool-suite

I have created some custom ds fields for a content type through code. That fields are displaying in the manage display settings of that content type.

I am creating a detail page for that content type using page manager. I am able to display the node fields but I can't access that custom ds fields in the page manager to display.

Any Idea about how to get custom ds fields in the page manager?

Comment: did u add field info?

Comment: I have created the fields using hook_ds_fields_info() and its `ui_limit =>contentype|full`.